# Documentation/Sample to integrate official WebRTC SDK into Android / iOS APP

Tags: android, ios, webrtc

I figured out that webrtc.org recently released Android and iOS Libraries to support WebRTC inside native mobile apps:

https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleWebRTC

https://bintray.com/google/webrtc/google-webrtc

I am searching for a documentation or sample app for these libraries. Does anybody have some information?

Some development questions:

- How can I do the signaling process using these SDKs (with my existing WebRTC server)?
- Which operating systems/devices are supported?
- Where can I get a sample app that uses these SDKs? All apps I found have other integration

At all I wasn't able to find any documentation...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's telling that even now (March 2018) there is no answer. I'm also starting to look into connecting iOS/Android to a WebRTC backend and have found nothing about using the correct methods.

Comment: Same here. Though they share how to install the framework natively there really isn't any real information on how to use the framework on the native platforms, iOS/Android.

Comment: Check this link - https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/main/examples

Answer (score 0):

[Android](https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo)

[ioS](https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios)

Yeah, Google doesn't provide much for mobile webRTC